# dplyr approach to get the last row number with a positive value

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0)) %>% print()
df[1:max(which(df$a>0)),]
```

[This little code chunk above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210344/how-to-get-the-last-row-number-with-a-positive-value) determines that the 7th row of `df` is the last row to contain a positive value, and filters every row after this 7th row out of the data frame.

I go from this

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
       a
   <dbl>
 1    1.
 2    2.
 3    3.
 4    0.
 5    5.
 6    0.
 7    7.
 8    0.
 9    0.
10    0.
```

to this

```
# A tibble: 7 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1    1.
2    2.
3    3.
4    0.
5    5.
6    0.
7    7.
```

How can I perform this `df[1:max(which(df$a>0)),]` using dplyr tidyverse slang? I need to learn base R, *and will*, but right now I got to do this in the tidyverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `slice`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  slice(1:max(which(a > 0)))


#      a
#   <dbl>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     0
#5     5
#6     0
#7     7
```

---

Or `filter`, where we select the rows which are less than the `max` index of `a > 0`.

```
df %>%
  filter(row_number() <= max(which(a > 0)))
```